# How to create many to many relationship between two tables using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having users and forums tables. User has contributed in many forums and Forum has many users

My database tables

```
users
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | user_one   |
|  2 | user_two   |
|  3 | user_three |
+----+------------+ 
forums
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | forum1 |
|  2 | forum2 |
|  3 | forum3 |
+----+--------+
users_forums
+---------+----------+
| user_id | forum_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        3 |
|       3 |        2 |
|       2 |        1 |
+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many.

You can create the **UserForum** model or **users_forums** table to pass secondary option in relationship.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(24))

    forums = relationship("Forum", secondary='users_forums')

class Forum(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'forums'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(24))

    users = relationship("User", secondary='users_forums')

class UserForum(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users_forums'
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    forum_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('forums.id'))
```

using as follow

```
user = User.query.get(1)
print(user)
<User 1>

forums = user.forums
print(forums)
[<Forum 1>, <Forum 2>]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQLAlchemy UserModel you need to use a relationship like the following:

```py
    forum_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("forum.id"), nullable=False)
    forum = db.relationship("ForumModel")
```

Then in your ForumModel you link them with something like:

```py
    users = db.relationship("UserModel", lazy="dynamic")
```

Read more here https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships